# Error following Django App Engine flexible tutorial

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am having some trouble following google's tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

Everything works fine till I get to the point of running `python manage.py migrate` at which point the error was:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: If set, STATIC_URL must end with a slash`

Note that google's documentation specifically says:

5. Set the value of STATIC_URL to '/static.'

Nonetheleess, I changed the settings.py to set `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` (which was the default to begin with), and got the error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'`

I could not resolve either of the errors. The SQL driver in use is `mysqlclient` and python 3 is used. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The first error and the second error are not related. The second error says you don't have the mysql driver installed. If this is python 3 MySQLdb isn't compatible with it.

Comment: It is indeed python 3, any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Comment: you can't use the Mysqldb driver at the moment, you will have to choose from one of the others available https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Comment: Looked at the page, I have "mysqlclient" as the driver, not "mysqldb" - mysqlclient appears to support python 3.

Comment: that's not what your error says

Comment: When I look at the list of packages installed on my computer, it says `'mysqlclient==1.3.8'` but no mention of `mysql-python` or `mysqldb` or anything related.

Comment: I see that you might be referring to this line in the settings: `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'`, How do I get it to use mysqlclient?